# Rails 4 HTTParty Docusign api invalid base 64 string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, httprequest, docusignapi, httparty

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

I am sending an envelope request post using HTTParty to the Docusign api and keep getting an error that states:
`The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character`

Here is my HTTP post:

`req = HTTParty.post(baseUrl,
            body:  {
                "status": "sent",
                "emailSubject": "Send this already",
                "documents": [{
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "test.pdf"
                }],
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [{
                        "name": "joe dirt",
                        "email": "joe.dirte@gmail.com",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "routingOrder": "1",
                        "tabs": {
                            "signHereTabs": [{
                                "xPosition": "150",
                                "yPosition": "200",
                                "documentId": "1",
                                "pageNumber": "2"
                            }],
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }.to_json,
            headers: {
            "Content-Type" => "application/json",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "Base64",
            'X-DocuSign-Authentication' => '{
            "Username" : "blah-blahblah-blah-blah-blah",
            "Password" : "blah",
            "IntegratorKey" : "blah-blah-blah-blah-blah"
            }'
            }, :debug_output => $stdout)`

The debugger spits out the following:

`"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
"Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
"Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
"Content-Length: 226\r\n"
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n"
"Expires: -1\r\n"`

This is the full request shown in my server :

`<- "POST /restapi/v2/accounts/1906554/envelopes HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nX-Docusign-Authentication: {
\n            \"Username\" : \"blah-blah-blah-b;ah-blah\",
\n            \"Password\" : \"blah\",
\n            \"IntegratorKey\" : \"blah-blah-blah-blah-blah\"
\n            }\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: demo.docusign.net\r\nContent-Length: 394\r\n\r\n"
<-"{
\"status\":\"sent\",
\"emailSubject\":\"Example of one recipient, type signer\",
\"documents\":[{
    \"documentId\":\"1\",
    \"name\":\"RE Ally MNDA_MAster.pdf\",
    \"documentBase64\":\"base64 document bytes...\"}],
    \"recipients\":{\"signers\":[{
        \"name\":\"joe dirt\",
        \"email\":\"joe.dirte@gmail.com\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
        \"routingOrder\":\"1\",
        \"tabs\":{
            \"signHereTabs\"[{
                \"xPosition\":\"150\",
                 \"yPosition\":\"200\",
                 \"documentId\":\"1\",
                 \"pageNumber\":\"2\"
            }]
        }
    }]
}"`

Per their documentations, I get a successful request for my baseURL when I make as such:

```
HTTParty.get('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information', headers: {
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'X-DocuSign-Authentication' => '{
                "Username" : "blah-bla-blah-bla-blah",
                "Password" : "blahword1",
                "IntegratorKey" : "blah-blah-blah-blah-blah"
                }'
                }
        )
```

[This is how docusign is expecting my post to look](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/quickstart.html)

Comment: Above shown object is a entire JSON object?

Comment: Well, it should be. As you can see, I've added the .to_json function onto my httparty request to make the conversion. I'll add what the request looks like now in my server.

Comment: Why are you using `' '` value for `X-DocuSign-Authentication`? Please check  `{
            "Username" : "blah-blahblah-blah-blah-blah",
            "Password" : "blah",
            "IntegratorKey" : "blah-blah-blah-blah-blah"
            }'`

Comment: With http party that was the only way I could get authentication to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions offered really worked for me but I was able to get the send request through on my templates by changing the code on my body. Not sure why the 'Quick Start' process did not work for me.

```
body:  {
            "emailSubject": "DocuSign API call - Request Signature - Boom",
            "templateId": "blahblah-blah-blah-blah-blahblah",
            "templateRoles": [{
                "email": "blah.l.lablah@gmail.com",
                "name": "la Leunblahg",
                "title": "El Hefe",
                "roleName": "Employee"
            }],
            "status": "sent"
        }.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `"Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "Base64"`, in your headers. Remove that.

Comment: If I remove that line, then I get an error stating `"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. \"\r\n}"`

Comment: Andrew is correct. The content type is json. Only one field in the json object is base64 encoded. Show us the sent/received headers and data from the DocuSign logging feature.

Comment: I have added the link to the docusign documentation and also added the full post request along with a successful login get for basurl. My authentication seems to go through just fine, it's when it gets into the body that I feel is where I am having my trouble

Comment: Maybe it might be easier if I knew what this line does: `\"documentBase64\":\"base64 document bytes...\"}],` the api docs don't really mention what this is and where to find the `base64 document bytes`

Comment: I'm 1 day new to the Docusign API so I really appreciate all of the help guys, not even sure I am doing the process correctly. I have a template uploaded and just need to populate a name within that template and send it to an email.